# React: Image is not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, visibility

Im folgenden Code sieht man wie ich das bild darstellen möchte, das Bild wird aber nicht angzeigt, nur der text wird angezeigt.

`<div> <b> Test123 </b> <image src={require('../../assets/images/homepage/homepage-splash-1.jpeg')} alt='loading...'></image> </div>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your image first outside the class of react view file. Like on the top like this:

```
import imageName from 'images/yourImageName.png';
```

Now inside the class of react file you can call this image like this:

```
<img src={imageName}  alt="Image Title"/>
```

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not work, but it should be. It will certainly be such a stupid error

Comment: May I know the error you're getting?

Comment: I dont get an error, i also can see it with the browser inspector but i cant see it rendered and there is no css

Comment: Ohh! That's really strange. You can also do one more option. You can give a class name to your img tag and inside CSS file you can write like `.imgClassName { display: block !important }`

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, one way to use local image address is to import it. something like this:

```
import homePageSplash from "../../assets/images/homepage/homepage-splash-1.jpeg"

return (<img src={homePageSplash} alt="" />)
```

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not work, but it should be. It will certainly be such a stupid error

Comment: could you please explain more about error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `require` here. Only specify the path to the image

```
<image src='../../assets/images/homepage/homepage-splash-1.jpeg' alt='loading...'></image>
```

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it did not work, but it should be. It will certainly be such a stupid error

Comment: Check path properly.

Comment: Path is correct :D